# Installing JavaScript Package on Bubble.is

Tags: javascript

How would I install a JavaScript package on a Bubble.is website? I have heard that it requires a custom plugin but I am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed the necessary documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can add JavaScript libraries in the header of any page using a  tag inside of Bubble (either in an "html element" or in the page header itself).  If you require custom javascript code, you'll have to build a plugin inside of Bubble in Bubble's "plugin editor" IDE.  Here, you will be able to use javascript to build custom integrations.  Currently, Bubble supports javascript and JQuery so if you are thinking about using things like React, Vue, etc. you will have to wait.  Instructions for building custom plugins on Bubble can be found at:
https://manual.bubble.is/building-plugins.html

Comment: So, if I place the code for TimeMe.js in the custom plugin and then call the TimeMe code on a certain page, TimeMe will track the amount of time I spend on a page?

Comment: This would be very simple to do, and possible even without writing a plugin.  It looks like you need to run their code on your own server or use cdnjs to import their library into your Bubble app via the page header (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TimeMe.js/2.0.0/timeme.min.js).  Then you'll need to initialize it using vanilla javascript.  You can enter this javascript into Bubble's html element, while remembering to contain that code inside of script tags....you will not need to write a plugin.

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TimeMe.js/2.0.0/timeme.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
 TimeMe.initialize({
  currentPageName: "my-home-page", // current page
  idleTimeoutInSeconds: 30 // seconds
 });  
</script>

Comment: So if I want to run the code —— TimeMe.callWhenUserLeaves(function(){
heap.track("Time on Page",{Minutes: TimeMe.getTimeOnCurrentPageInSeconds()/60});
}); ——, then would I put this in the header or as a run JavaScript isn’t he workflow once a page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

First include the required package in an HTML element or under: Settings > SEO > "Script in the body"

Then install the [Toolbox plugin](https://bubble.io/plugin/toolbox-1488796042609x768734193128308700) which will allow you to call the desired function in a workflow.

Visual demonstration can be seen here: https://youtu.be/Qo6YPhqfoJ4?t=78